# Вызов хранимой процедуры из БД для поиска значений в DataGridView. Ошибка: отсутствует операнд после оператора "proc26"."

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

В `Windows.Forms` при нажатии на кнопку необходимо осуществить поиск совпадений в DataGridView, условие поиска которого записано в хранимой процедуре. В `TextBox` записывается вводимое значение. При попытке сделать это выдает ошибку:

> отсутствует операнд после оператора "proc26"."

Вот часть кода программы:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dvLocality = dtTours.DefaultView;
    dvLocality.RowFilter = "call proc26(" + LocalitytextBox.Text + ")"; // в этой строке ошибка
}
```

Comment: `DataView` - это `System.Data.DataView`? Он не умеет делать запросы в базу данных. Свойство `RowFilter` фильтрует данные, загруженные в `DataTable`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, это `System.Data.DataView`. Понял